# WooCommerce Bookings - How to trigger ajax recalc with input custom buttons

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I'm trying to customize the input buttons, but when I update the amount by the custom buttons, the value doesn't update.

I'm copying overwriting the file in the path: woocommerce-booking/booking-form/number.php

This is another file template that I believe is useful to understand my need: woocommerce-booking/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/booking.php

```
<p class="form-field form-field-wide <?php echo esc_attr( implode( ' ', $class ) ); ?>">
  <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?>:</label>

  <!-- Custom Input Button -->
  <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" class="minus">-</button>

  <input type="number" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $min ) ) ? esc_attr( $min ) : 0; ?>"
    step="<?php echo ( isset( $step ) ) ? esc_attr( $step ) : ''; ?>"
    min="<?php echo ( isset( $min ) ) ? esc_attr( $min ) : ''; ?>"
    max="<?php echo ( isset( $max ) ) ? esc_attr( $max ) : ''; ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>"
    id="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>" /> <?php echo ( ! empty( $after ) ) ? esc_html( $after ) : ''; ?>

  <!-- Custom Input Button -->
  <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus">+</button>
</p>
```

Comment: JS code has no issue in the given code snippet, so there might be some kind of conflict or event prevent might be applied to your website.

Comment: @VijayHardaha I had to add e.preventDefault on the buttons enqueuing a script because they were doing the submit function

Comment: you can add `type=button` in the button attribute as well. it's a good practice to define button type whenever you use a button tag.

Comment: I've tried everything, I can't find a solution.